# vim: Execute gq on whole buffer on save

Tags: vim

I use `gq` to format my Go code. I set `formatprg=goimports`.
I want to execute `gq` on save automatically. I added this line in my vimrc:

```
au BufWritePost *.go normal gggqG
```

This works great, but the one thing is, because of `G`, my cursor goes to the bottom line in the buffer when I save the file (by `:w`) .
I want to keep my cursor place after running `gq`. How can I do this?

I know some plugins enable to do this, but I prefer not using them.

Comment: <C-o> a few times? check `:h jump-motions`  or `:jumps`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably use `:help BufWritePre`, which fires *before* the write, instead of `:help BufWritePost`, which fires *after* the write.

Second, what you want to do is typically achieved by saving the state of the window (scroll position, cursor position, etc.) *before* the action that moves the cursor, and restore it afterwards:

```
" in after/ftplugin/go.vim
setlocal formatprg=goimports
function! GoFormat()
    let w:v = winsaveview()
    silent normal gggqG
    call winrestview(w:v)
endfunction
augroup Go
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call GoFormat()
augroup END
```

[image: gofmt]

I used `gofmt` for the GIF because I don't have `goimports`, but the mechanism described above is generic enough to work with pretty much every competently written formatter out there.

See `:help winsaveview()` and `:help winrestview()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it will jump back to line 4 after save the file

```
au BufWritePost *.sh exe "normal! ggG\<c-o>\<c-o>"
```

```
# bin
a=1
b=2
c=3 <=edit something and put cursor here and save file
d=4
e=5
f=6
```